# Gatling - Concatenate JSON files within static JSON content

Tags: json, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

**Galing version : 3.3.1**

I am trying to post json payloads using multiple files. These files contain a segment of a bigger JSON payload [unique json file for each user].

Since each Json file is a segment/child of bigger JSON, I need to concatenate files inside static JSON content.
This is the point where I am stuck and need help.

eg :
**Entire json structure** :-

```
{
"Static element1" : "Static value",
"Static element2" : "Static value",
"data" : {
"this part of json will come from JSON files generated by Development team"
}
{
```

I am still learning Gatling and before posting this question, I tried searching the solution from exisitng posts
but was not able to find or implement with my limited knowledge.

Approach I tried as a first step was to add a single JSON file path through EL language within the static content through a feeder.
If one file could be posted, then I was planning to work on adding a counter to iterate through all files.

**Custom feeder with file path** [for now I am using a single file, but eventually will have to use multiple] :

```
 val customFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map(
    "fileName" -> ElFileBody("bodies/createAccount_0.json")
  ))
```

```
  .feed(customFeeder)
     .exec(http("Create New Account")
      .post("/messages")
       .body(StringBody("{" +
         "\n\t\"Static element1\": \"Static value\"," +
         "\n\t\"Static element2\": \"Static value\"," +

         "\n\"data\":"

         //I was trying following three options, certainly wrong, as I could not create proper request
            //  Approach 1 to give the file path directly without using custom feeder
                    //  + ElFileBody(("bodies/databodies/create_Account_0.json"))

            //  Approach 2 to give the file path through custom feeder  
                    //  + """${fileName}"""

            //  Approach 3 to create a JSON with static content and passing file name as a prameter.
                    // .body(ElFileBody("bodies/CreateAccountFullBody.json")).asJson

        + "\n\"}\"")).asJson
           .check(status.is(201)))
```

**File "bodies/CreateAccountFullBody.json" used in 3rd approach**

```
{
Static element1 : "Static value",
Static element2 : "Static value",
data :
  "data":"${fileName}"
}
```

**Response** --

```
Through cosole output I see that the JSON was not fed.
byteArraysBody={
        "Static element1": "Static value",
        "Static element2": "Static value",
"data":<function1>
"}"
```